# load mysql jar in runtime

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin that connects to database. I don't want to bundle the jar for the driver in my plugin. 
Instead i want to take it from the users project and load it in run-time. Below is the code I am using to achieve the same. 
I get the error "No suitable driver found......" from line 3. 
The same line works fine when i use Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); and include the jar in my plugin.
Please point out what could be wrong.

```
/*urls = [file:/C:/veni/code/TestFC/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar] */
final ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);  //1
loader.loadClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");            //2
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testfc",username,paswd); //3
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to use a JDBC driver from an arbitrary location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288828/how-to-use-a-jdbc-driver-from-an-arbitrary-location)

Comment: The issue is, the `DriverManager` is loaded in a different class loader from the `Driver`, but class loaders don't scan child class loaders for classes, they only scan parent class loaders

Comment: final ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);             final Driver driver = (Driver) loader.loadClass(MYSQL_JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();
     DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
     DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:mysql://localhost/TestFc");                      the last line gives error that driver not found....does that mean that the driver was not loaded?

Comment: Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", "your_db_username");
props.put("password", "your_db_password");
Connection con = driver.connect("jdbc:mysql:...", props);                instead of using DriverManager, i tried the above code and it works. refer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/5674762/1081017