# Adding JDBC driver at runtime - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, spring, maven, jdbc, spring-boot

I am trying to add an external jar at runtime and then use that jar to connect to a database (instead of having to add many drivers to the pom, the goal is to provide the user the ability to load any driver jar at runtime). I am using a spring boot project and I am trying to use spring boots [DataSourceBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceBuilder.html) to create the datasource.

The answers and suggestions in [Loading JDBC Driver at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674637/loading-jdbc-driver-at-runtime) and [Loading jars at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624907/loading-jars-at-runtime) do not seem to work for the following code:

```
@Component
public class DriverLoader {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?useSSL=false";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String ADMIN = "admin";
    private static final String DRIVER_JAR = "C:\\Users\\Sander\\Downloads\\mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar";

    @PostConstruct
    private void loadDriver() throws Exception {
        File file = new File(DRIVER_JAR);
        if (file != null) {
            URLClassLoader URLClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {file.toURI().toURL()}, System.class.getClassLoader());
            String driverName = DatabaseDriver.fromJdbcUrl(URL).getDriverClassName();
            System.out.println(driverName);

            // lets try to load the class
            Class<?> driverClass = URLClassLoader.loadClass(driverName);
            Driver actualDriver = (Driver) driverClass.newInstance();
            URLClassLoader.close();

            // Throws: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils
            /*Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("user", USER);
            properties.put("password", ADMIN);
            Connection con = actualDriver.connect(URL, properties);*/           

            DataSource dataSource = createNewDataSource(URL, USER, ADMIN);

            if (dataSource != null) {
                // lets try to connect
                // Throws: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
                dataSource.getConnection().isValid(1);
            }           
        }       
    }

    public DataSource createNewDataSource(String url, String username, String password) {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url(url)       
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .build();
    }    
}
```

Snippet of the pom I am using:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>           
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

How can I use the DataSourceBuilder to succesfully establish a connection with a datasource given that the jar file has been added at runtime?

Full stack trace:

```
2017-02-04 20:13:22.201 ERROR 12528 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6;ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:283) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:732) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:479) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at nl.mierasmade.driver.DriverLoader.loadDriver(DriverLoader.java:54) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) [spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) [spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) [spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at nl.mierasmade.JdbcRuntimeDriverApplication.main(JdbcRuntimeDriverApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6;ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:56) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:271) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:38) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Try to not close URLClassLoader, what happens?

Comment: Same exception. The documentation states "Also, any classes or resources that are already loaded, are still accessible. ", so closing it shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Not all classes could be loaded from that jar, so closing could also be the reason... It is strange that loading class and creating new instance is ok, but it is not after close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get to work like this:

```
  @Bean
  public DataSource dynamicDataSource() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file:///C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/h2-1.4.193.jar")}, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
    DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().url('jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1').build();
    dataSource.getConnection().isValid(10);
    return dataSource;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` or `Thread.getContextClassLoader()` instead of using system's class loader. Refer [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-system-classloader) section **E.5.2 System ClassLoader**

Comment: Both `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` as `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` throw the class not found exception. Thanks for the link.