# Loading Jar at run time and access all the classes

Tags: java

I need to add a jar at run time from path provided in the config file. Let us call it `run-time.jar`.

My original jar is `original.jar`. I am importing classes from `run-time.jar` directly in my `original.jar`. At compilation time I have a sample version of `run-time.jar` to help me through compilation issues. I am building a thin jar with out dependencies.

I am planning to use `URLClassLoader` to load classes at run time. My sample code in `original.jar` is

```
// Importing class from run-time.jar
import run.time.Test

class Original {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*Code to load classes from jar file*/

    Test newTest = new Test(); 
    newTest.runTests(); 
  }
}
```

Will this approach work or is there any suggestion to do it better. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Reference: [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime/60775#60775)

Comment: Yes: `URLClassLoader` is the way to go.

Comment: The correct way to do this is with [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).  You should not read a .jar file directly to load its classes.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is sometimes used to load JDBC drivers at runtime, you can get some inspiration from this thread: [Loading JDBC Driver at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674637/loading-jdbc-driver-at-runtime)

I suppose to find out whether this works for your jar, just try it out. But I think your classloader hack should work for Java version < 9.

However from a code quality point of view, this is not a very clean solution as I am sure you are aware of. Have you considered looking into OSGi?